# Pass parameters from one rmarkdown page to another?

Tags: r-markdown

Thank you in advance. I am writing an rmarkdown script that outputs a pdf. It does a bunch of SQL queries based upon user inputs (I'm using the "knit with parameters" option now, but open to ideas).

I need the output pdf to go to a specific location. While I could do all of this manually, I'm trying to make this friendly to people with limited R experience.

The best I've found is using the render function, but I don't think you can render an Rmd file from inside itself.

So, is it possible to create an Rmd that prompts users for the inputs, passes these inputs to the Rmd that does the calculations and pdf creation, and then allows me to put this in a specified location?

Oh and finally, the location is dynamic - changing based on the inputs from the user.

Am I crazy? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO. Can you share some code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: No clue about rmarkdown so far, but could this help you? https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html